# I have two array in my o/p. one is result array and the other is data array how to merge both array's into a single array matching the coordinates

Tags: javascript, arrays

how to merge both arrays into a single array matching the first array coordinates with second array's originToDestinedpointDirectionUrl lat and long?

I have used  with object.assign and merged both the arrays but I did not see the match between the coordinates in result array and data array

```
 o/p:
    {
        "result": [
            {
                "id": "2X56cPnr0mvS9Cq8MAW1jQ",
                "alias": "the-hot-tomato-fruita",
                "name": "The Hot Tomato",
                "coordinates": {
                    "latitude": 39.1594399,
                    "longitude": -108.732141
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "bGNVfuaRoIpPdUKsfROfZQ",
                "alias": "camillas-kaffe-fruita",
                "name": "Camilla's Kaffe",
                "coordinates": {
                    "latitude": 39.1588374652023,
                    "longitude": -108.732291567344
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "jZtuJxbKfS8s4QCe_TrTxw",
                "alias": "colorado-national-monument-fruita",
                "name": "Colorado National Monument",
                "coordinates": {
                    "latitude": 39.097564,
                    "longitude": -108.7387526
                }
          }

    ],
    "data": [
    {
                "originToDestinedpointDirectionUrl": "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Los Angeles, CA, USA/39.097564,-108.7387526"
    },
    {
                "originToDestinedpointDirectionUrl": "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Los Angeles, CA, USA/39.1594399,-108.732141"
     },
     {
                "originToDestinedpointDirectionUrl": "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Los Angeles, CA, USA/39.1588374652023,-108.732291567344"
  }
```

]
}

expected o/p:

```
{
    "third array": [
        {
            "id": "2X56cPnr0mvS9Cq8MAW1jQ",
            "alias": "the-hot-tomato-fruita",
            "name": "The Hot Tomato",
            "coordinates": {
                "latitude": 39.1594399,
                "longitude": -108.732141
            },
            "originToDestinedpointDirectionUrl": "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Los Angeles, CA, USA/39.1594399,-108.732141"

        },
        {
            "id": "bGNVfuaRoIpPdUKsfROfZQ",
            "alias": "camillas-kaffe-fruita",
            "name": "Camilla's Kaffe",
            "coordinates": {
                "latitude": 39.1588374652023,
                "longitude": -108.732291567344
            },
            "originToDestinedpointDirectionUrl": "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Los Angeles, CA, USA/39.1588374652023,-108.732291567344"

        },
        {
            "id": "jZtuJxbKfS8s4QCe_TrTxw",
            "alias": "colorado-national-monument-fruita",
            "name": "Colorado National Monument",
            "coordinates": {
                "latitude": 39.097564,
                "longitude": -108.7387526
            },
        "originToDestinedpointDirectionUrl": "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Los Angeles, CA, USA/39.097564,-108.7387526"

      }

]
```

Comment: `I have used with object.assign and merged both the arrays` - where? There is no such code in your question

Comment: ya, I removed it because I did not find it as a correct scenario so I removed it. I was trying to say that I tried that scenario. @JaromandaX

Comment: Well first of all you have to make the array-structures similar to be able to compare the coordinates.

I'd propably convert the data in your "data" array first.

Comment: I  have tried sortting the first array in order to compare to the second one . I did not find One the exactly matches@HenrikClausen

Comment: I hope that didn't appear rude, I've been accused of being rude when I point this out in the past. It's not rude, it's just stating what is expected here at stack overflow, but apparently, only *some special* people are allowed to point it out - and I'm not special enough yet, apparently

Comment: I didn't expect anyone to write code and give it to me. I just wanted to know if there any way of finding it @JaromandaX

Comment: Share the expected output please

Comment: @Rahul: You have to create an array that matches..
That means splitting this string in to URL and coordinates:
"https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Los Angeles, CA, USA/39.097564,-108.7387526"

Comment: After splitting the string and getting the coordinates you could iterate through the forst array and locate matches with the array.find function.
You may have to account for tolerance in the coordinates as they might not match 100%

Comment: @RAHULSRV: Do have a look at my solution

Comment: Thanks@Isaac, I find your solution Helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let op = {
        "result": [
            {
                "id": "2X56cPnr0mvS9Cq8MAW1jQ",
                "alias": "the-hot-tomato-fruita",
                "name": "The Hot Tomato",
                "coordinates": {
                    "latitude": 39.1594399,
                    "longitude": -108.732141
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "bGNVfuaRoIpPdUKsfROfZQ",
                "alias": "camillas-kaffe-fruita",
                "name": "Camilla's Kaffe",
                "coordinates": {
                    "latitude": 39.1588374652023,
                    "longitude": -108.732291567344
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "jZtuJxbKfS8s4QCe_TrTxw",
                "alias": "colorado-national-monument-fruita",
                "name": "Colorado National Monument",
                "coordinates": {
                    "latitude": 39.097564,
                    "longitude": -108.7387526
                }
          }

    ],
    "data": [
    {
                "originToDestinedpointDirectionUrl": "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Los Angeles, CA, USA/39.097564,-108.7387526"
    },
    {
                "originToDestinedpointDirectionUrl": "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Los Angeles, CA, USA/39.1594399,-108.732141"
     },
     {
                "originToDestinedpointDirectionUrl": "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Los Angeles, CA, USA/39.1588374652023,-108.732291567344"
    }
] };

let resultArr = op.result;
let dataArr = op.data;

let thirdArray = [];

dataArr.forEach(data => {
  let splittedArr = data.originToDestinedpointDirectionUrl.split("/");
  let coordinate = splittedArr[splittedArr.length-1].split(",");

  let corLat = coordinate[0];
  let corLong = coordinate[1];

  resultArr.forEach(res => {

    if(res.coordinates.latitude == corLat && res.coordinates.longitude == corLong){
      thirdArray.push({ "id": res.id, "alias": res.alias, "name": res.name, "coordinates": res.coordinates, "originToDestinedpointDirectionUrl": data })
    }
  });
});

console.log(thirdArray);
```

There is some string splitting involved in order to grab the coordinates and to compare afterwards. Do let me know if it's not what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by having logic something like below. I have used `map` to create new array having required object structure and added logic for mapping co-ordinates with URL within callback of map.

```js
let obj = {
        "result": [
            {
                "id": "2X56cPnr0mvS9Cq8MAW1jQ",
                "alias": "the-hot-tomato-fruita",
                "name": "The Hot Tomato",
                "coordinates": {
                    "latitude": 39.1594399,
                    "longitude": -108.732141
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "bGNVfuaRoIpPdUKsfROfZQ",
                "alias": "camillas-kaffe-fruita",
                "name": "Camilla's Kaffe",
                "coordinates": {
                    "latitude": 39.1588374652023,
                    "longitude": -108.732291567344
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "jZtuJxbKfS8s4QCe_TrTxw",
                "alias": "colorado-national-monument-fruita",
                "name": "Colorado National Monument",
                "coordinates": {
                    "latitude": 39.097564,
                    "longitude": -108.7387526
                }
          }

    ],
    "data": [
    {
                "originToDestinedpointDirectionUrl": "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Los Angeles, CA, USA/39.097564,-108.7387526"
    },
    {
                "originToDestinedpointDirectionUrl": "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Los Angeles, CA, USA/39.1594399,-108.732141"
     },
     {
                "originToDestinedpointDirectionUrl": "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Los Angeles, CA, USA/39.1588374652023,-108.732291567344"
  }
] }

let finalArray = obj.result.map((element) => {
  let url = obj.data.find((urlObj) => urlObj.originToDestinedpointDirectionUrl.indexOf(`${element.coordinates.latitude},${element.coordinates.longitude}` > -1))
  element.originToDestinedpointDirectionUrl = url.originToDestinedpointDirectionUrl;
  return element;
})

console.log(finalArray);
```

Comment: Thank you for Replying.@User97